# Combo in dhtmlxGrid

Tags: dhtmlx

How can i set a combo in dhtmlxGrid?

I did something like below, still when i dblclick on cell i am unable to see the combo.
i have initialized a dhtmlxwindow and attached a 1c layout.
Then attached a grid to cell a.

```
var dhxWindow = new dhtmlxWindow();
var popupWin = dhxWindow.createWindow('winName', xPos, yPos, width, hieght);
popupWin.setText(winTitle);
popupWin.setModal(true);
popupWin.denyPark();
popupWin.denyResize();
popupWin.show();
popupWin.centerOnScreen();
var layout = popupWin.attachLayout('1C');
var mygrid = layout.cells('a').attachGrid();
mygrid.loadXML('grid.jsp');

And my jsp:

    <%@page contentType="text/xml" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <rows> 
    <head> 
         <column width="50" type="ed" align="right" color="white" sort="str">Sales</column>
    <column width="80" type="co" align="left" sort="str">Shipping
        <option value="1">1 Day</option>
        <option value="7">1 Week</option> 
    </column> 
    </head> 
    <row> 
    <cell></cell>
    <cell></cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the issue cannot be reproduced locally. Your code works well for us.
If the issue still occurs for you, please, open a ticket at http://support.dhtmlx.com/ and provide a complete demo, or a demo link where your issue can be reconstructed.